# How get html of div by class name on prototype

Tags: prototypejs

I am before work in JQuery and i am a little don't understood how i can get `<a>asd</a>` of `.quote_content` on prototype

```
<div class="quote_content">
     <a>asd</a>
</div>
```

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

I have a function which do that:

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
function showCompare() {
    var quote_content = $$(".quote_content");
    win = new Window({className: "mac_os_x", title: "Sample", width:800, height:400, destroyOnClose: true, recenterAuto:false});

    win.getContent().innerHTML = quote_content;
    win.showCenter();
}
// ]]></script>
```

But `quote_content` output is `[object HTMLDivElement]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, if all you want to do is go through a page finding any element with the classname quote_content and return its HTML content:

```
$$('.quote_content').each(function(elm){
  // do whatever you like with elm.innerHTML
  alert( elm.innerHTML );
  // note that any whitespace, as in your example
  // will be preserved. You may prefer this instead:
  var child = elm.down();
  alert( child.outerHTML );
  // this only works if you know there is only one
  // child element, though
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to know is class attribute is identify it with a point after the class name,
in you'r case `.quote_content` then you must go for the child element, I know 2 ways to do that.

1-

```
$('.quote_content > a')
```

2-

```
$('.quote_content').children("a")
```

or if the child element have a class:

1-

```
$('.quote_content > .child_element_class')
```

2-

```
$('.quote_content').children(".child_element_class")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function showCompare() { 
  var quote_content = document.getElementById('quote_content'); 
  console.log(quote_content); 
  win = new Window({className: "mac_os_x", title: "Sample", width:800, height:400, destroyOnClose: true,   recenterAuto:false});

  win.getContent().innerHTML = quote_content.innerHTML; 
  win.showCenter(); 
}
```